# Is it possible to suspend computer while connected with VPN and then restore?

Tags: suspend, vpn

I am using Ubuntu 22.04. My activities are mainly to code and run things, for this I use Geany and the Gnome Terminal, as well as Nautilus as file explorer. When working on stuff that is in my local PC I can at any point suspend my computer (i.e. sleep), go to do something else and when I come back it wakes up and all the windows resume their normal operation so I continue working. Now, sometimes I have to work on a remote PC through a VPN. For this I SSH with the terminal into the remote computer to execute things, I mount with SFTP the remote file system to navigate it with Nautilus and simply double click on the files to open them with Geany. The problem is that if now I suspend the computer (or disconnect the VPN) everything crashes, no matter if afterwards I connect the VPN again. This forces me to open everything up again with each break, or having to left the computer (and the connection) running when I am not working, which is really inconvenient. Is there any way to get the same behavior as when working in a local PC but when working in the remote PC?